# String not matching in django/python

Tags: python, django, django-views

the problem i have that if condition is not working. both p.user and username gives same value when i write `print(p.user)` & `print(username)` but still it is not matching and when i print context it always have false value for author.

```
def post_full(request, username, slug):

    post = Post.objects.filter(slug = slug)
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug)
    files = file.objects.filter(Post = instance)
    context = {'post': instance,'file':files}
    for p in post:
        if p.user==username:
            context.update({'author': True})
        else:
            context.update({'author': False})
    try:
        slug = request.POST["query"]
        if slug:
            print(slug)
            query = slugify(slug)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/search/%s/'%query)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: try `username.strip()`

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: strip on `p.user` as well. And also check for the letter case

Comment: well it worked.

Comment: what does strip do?

Comment: str.strip([chars]) -  it removes the specified characters from beginning or end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to strip out the spaces during equality check.

```
if p.user.strip()==username.strip():
```

And also it's better to do apply `strip` before saving the data to db. By this way, we don't need apply `strip` on db object while during equality check.

[`string.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) will remove all the unnecessary leading and trailing spaces.